# ISAPI Rewrite detect root folder

Tags: redirect, url-rewriting, isapi-rewrite

Using ISAPI Rewrite I'm looking for a way to detect if a given URL contains only one subfolder and then rewriting the URL.

```
www.mysite.com/Cloud     => true
www.mysite.com/Cloud/    => false
www.mysite.com/Cloud/One => false
www.mysite.com/Cloud.xml => false
```

the result should be the URL added with .html only for the true condition

```
www.mysite.com/Cloud.html
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the following:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

You did not specify if it's a 301-redirect or a rewrite. So in case it's 301-redirect, simply add R=301 in flags.